# Simple algebraic structures with infinite quantities, similar to the dual numbers and infinitesimals

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, derivatives, chain-rule

One of the most useful techniques I've ever learned is to use dual numbers to see what happens to some function $f(x)$ as $x \to $ some $r$. I will just evaluate $f(r+\epsilon)$ and multiply things out, and the automatic differentiation property of the dual numbers often ends up performing L'Hôpital's rule and etc for me. I have used this technique so many times I couldn't begin to count them all; I wish I'd learned about dual numbers and automatic differentiation much earlier.

I wish I had a similar technique to evaluate things as $x \to \infty$ this way.

I've often gotten this to work by simply treating $1/\epsilon$ as a formal quantity and just ignoring the fact that $1/\epsilon$ doesn't actually exist. Sometimes, doing that, it's possible to rewrite things in a way that these $1/\epsilon$ terms cancel out, or can otherwise be rewritten in terms of just regular $\epsilon$ terms, and then I can proceed with the automatic differentiation as usual. Having to do this is very tedious, however, and I hate it.

What I'm really looking for is something just as simple as the dual numbers which will do all of this for me. **Does there exist some extremely simple algebraic structure that gives us some easy way to represent infinite quantities instead of infinitesimal ones?**

Maybe a different real algebra, or maybe some kind of "extended real algebra" with elements squaring to $\infty$, or just something? Is it even possible to do this in a way that we get something associative?

Comment: Try the hyperreal numbers.  I write about them in my book "Calculus from the Ground Up."  You can see them in action in my paper "Hyperreal Numbers for Infinite Divergent Series".  I also have a simple YouTube video on them here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTXRnEKEn4k&list=PL2Ky2_VcYEd1-UmZxmNXaQh2AjKY8tpvI&index=1

Comment: @johnnyb thanks, I am very familiar - I think that was a bit beyond what I was going for here w/ dual numbers. The elegance of the dual numbers is that they are a simple 2D real algebra. I was thinking maybe the Levi-Civita field would be good for my purposes but I was still curious if something simpler could exist.